# SQL EXISTS returns all rows, more than two tables

Tags: sql, subquery, exists, correlated-subquery

I know similar questions like this have been asked before, but I have not seen one for more than 2 tables. And there seems to be a difference.

I have three tables from which I need fields, `customers` where I need `customerID` and `orderID` from, `orders` from which I get `customerID` and `orderID` and `lineitems` from which I get `orderID` and `quantity` (= quantity ordered).

I want to find out how many customers bought more than 2 of the same item, so basically quantity > 2 with:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT custID) 
FROM customers
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT *
    FROM customers C, orders O, lineitems L
    WHERE C.custID = O.custID AND O.orderID = L.orderID AND L.quantity > 2
    );
```

I do not understand why it is returning me the count of all rows. I am correlating the subqueries before checking the >2 condition, am I not?

I am a beginner at SQL, so I'd be thankful if you could explain it to me fundamentally, if necessary. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to repeat `customers` table in the `EXISTS` subquery. This is the idea of correlation: use the table of the outer query in order to correlate.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT custID) 
FROM customers c
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT *
    FROM orders O
    JOIN lineitems L ON O.orderID = L.orderID
    WHERE C.custID = O.custID AND L.quantity > 2
    );
```

Comment: So the error is caused by repeating customers again? Or does using `JOIN` instead of `FROM ... WHERE ...` also make a difference when using multiple tables?

Comment: @sandboxj Yes the error is due to the tables `customers` being used again: it beats the idea of correlation. It is also preferable to use modern `JOIN` syntax like in the query above instead of old-style syntax with comma separated tables.

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this as two aggregations:

```
select count(distinct customerid)
from (select o.customerid, l.itemid, count(*) as cnt
      from lineitems li join
           orders o
           on o.orderID = l.orderId
      group by o.customerid, l.itemid
     ) ol
where cnt >= 2;
```

The inner query counts the number of items that each customer has purchased.  The outer counts the number of customers.

EDIT:

I may have misunderstood the question for the above answer.  If you just want where `quantity >= 2`, then that is much easier:

```
select count(distinct o.customerid)
from lineitems li join
     orders o
     on o.orderID = l.orderId
where l.quantity >= 2;
```

This is probably the simplest way to express the query.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use "joins" ,

Try this

select 
        count(*)
        From 
        orders o
        inner join
        lineitems l
        on 
        l.orderID = o.orderID 
        where 
        l.quantity > 2